# JPA ManyToOne for class hierarchy

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
}

@Entity
public class D {
    @ManyToOne
    public A a;
}
```

The problem is class D and the field a (could be either of type B or C). What should be the mapping?

Comment: what is the issue ? are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference an `A` from another entity, then `A` should not be a MappedSuperclass, but an entity. You should annotate it with `@Entity`, and choose an [inheritance strategy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html).

Other than that, the mapping will stay as is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid in JPA, as relationships cannot be defined to @MappedSuperclass.

You could map A and @Entity (TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance would give you the same data model, but also consider JOINED or SINGLE_TABLE, as they are normally more efficient).

In EclipseLink you can also use a @VariableOneToOne for this type of relationship.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm#CHDDFDGF

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct. It will be the mapping A. So, in Table D ; we will have an additional column which will tell us if A is B or C.  In Toplink we have the column name as Type. Even in hibernate we have similar concept. And this column is automatically populated by the ORM.